# VSTS window close event

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, vssdk

I am using microsoft VSTS modal [dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/reference/client/controls/modaldialog?view=vsts)  and I want a confirmation message when modal dialog is closed from 'x' (closed button of modal dialog), I get close event which fired after event dialog is closed.

I want an event before closing the dialog. 
How can I do that?

Comment: please post some code of what you already have, so we can help you

Comment: There is no way to detect the event which closing the VSTS web page. And what do you want to do before vsts web page closing? Maybe VSTS service hooks or extensions can help.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I want to show confirmation pop up before closing vsts window

Comment: VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.Dialog).then(function(dialogService) {
var contributionId = //id
var dialogOptions = {
                                title: "ABC",
                                close: onDialogCloseByCrossButtonClick
                            };
dialogService.openDialog(contributionId, dialogOptions).then(function (dialog) {});

Comment: @JaveriaAnwer No, there is no way to do that. But when you close the page which has un-saved  changes, the browser will pop up to reminder you stay or leave.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT this is not happening in modal window of vsts

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT i tried from their [library link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/using-host-dialog?view=vsts)

Comment: @JaveriaAnwer The extension neither contribute to windows closing event. Beside, you can use the Modal Dialog only or a certain Hub/Tab/menu etc.